# failed to create the virtual hard disk hyper-v

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, vhd

I have 4 hyper-v servers running windows server 2012 R2 that they are in a cluster.
I want to create a new virtual machine but i get an error that "failed to create the virtual hard disk",right after i click on finish the virtual machine is created but not in cluster i see my machine from my hyper-v manager not from failover cluster manager. I have tried to create this VM on another hyper servers too and i also have created hard disk on another path but i still get the error
can someone please help me in this case.

Comment: Here are some approaches: https://serverfault.com/questions/905480/hyper-v-create-virtual-machine-operation-failed

Comment: Seconded. Also check the thread. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/57681dfd-c2e2-49cc-aac9-6fe8572825ec/unable-to-create-virtual-hard-disks-on-drives-other-than-c?forum=winserverhyperv Probably the problem is within storage. Ensure you choosing right storage while creating the VM.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to create the VM....
Check the File System format of the disk you use to create V-Disk, It must be compatible with the OS disk format (e.g. FAT32 or NTFS)... Windows Server used NTFS format, so make sure you format whatever drive to NTFS.. I hope this helps.

Dan